# How can I overload methods in Moops?

Tags: perl, moose, moops

I would like to overload some methods in Moops.

I have the tried the following code:

```
method setIdNum() {
      print "Please enter ID number: ";
      chomp (my $input = <STDIN>);
      $self->$idNum($input);
}

method setIdNum(Int $num) {
      $self->$idNum($num);
}
```

But it errors by saying setIdNum is redefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want multimethods, you have to ask for them explicitly by putting `multi` in front of the `method` keyword:

```
multi method setIdNum() {
  print "Please enter ID number: ";
  chomp (my $input = <STDIN>);
  $self->$idNum($input);
}

multi method setIdNum(Int $num) {
  $self->$idNum($num);
}
```

You may also need to explicitly ask for Kavorka support inside your class declaration:

```
class Whatever {
    use Kavorka qw( multi method );
  ...
```

Comment: Worked perfectly without the need to import Kavorka method! Thanks.